# How to post a static value in jqgrid when using inline edit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i want to post a static value to server, something like this `<input type="hidden" name="table_name" value="<?php echo $table_name; ?>">`
the value is not a part of colmodel, i want to post it whenever the inline edit happens,  this is my php file with jqgrid,

```
<head>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jq/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jq/grid.locale-en.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jq/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jq/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="rowed5"></table>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var lastsel2
var mydata=<?PHP echo $json_data;?>;
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    postData: {test_value:'<?PHP echo $table?>'},
    serializeCellData: function( post_to_server ) {
        var postParams  =  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
        if(postParams.hasOwnProperty('test_value') ) {
            post_to_server['test_value'] = postParams.test_value;
        }
        return post_to_server;
    },
    datatype: "local",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    data: mydata,
    height: 320,
    autowidth:true,
    colNames:['RowID','status','note','Variant ID'],
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55, sorttype:"int",align:"center"},
        {name:'status',index:'status', width:150,align:"left", editable: true,
edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"Exclude:Exclude"}},
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"10"}},
        {name:'v_id',index:'v_id', width:150,align:"left"}],
    /*onSelectRow: function(id){
        if(id && id!==lastsel2){
            jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
            jQuery('#rowed5').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
            lastsel2=id;
        }
    },*/
    editurl: "functions.php",
    cellEdit : true,
    cellsubmit : 'remote',
    cellurl : 'functions.php',
});
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch : "cn"});
</script>
</body>
```

i am able to post the colmodel values like:

```
if($_POST['oper']=='edit')
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
}
```

but i want to to post a static value which is not a part of colmodel.

**error**
    `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function
    at HTMLTableElement.serializeCellData (cam.php:224)
    at HTMLTableElement.serializeFeedback (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2278)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:8478)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.saveCell (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:8403)
    at n.fn.init.$.fn.jqGrid (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:2643)
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.src.js:8368)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use postData jqGrid parameter or serailizeRowData grid parameter. All of these are described [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options) and [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing)

You may want to look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255068/jqgrid-construct-postdata-array-using-a-functions-return-value)

EDIT:

In this case one possible solution is to use serializeRowData

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    ...
    postData: {test_value:'<?PHP echo $table?>'},
    serializeRowData : function( post_to_server ) {
        var postParams  =  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
        if(postParams.hasOwnProperty('test_value') ) {
            post_to_server['test_value'] = postParams.test_value;
        }
        return post_to_server;
    },
    datatype: "local",
    ...
 });
```

In order this to work, please be a sure that your variable $table has a value. The simple test if this work is to set a static value in postData object instead of variable.

```
jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({
    postData: {test_value:'mystaticvalue'},
...
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reference links sir, is this below  line suffice to meet the requirement? kindly advice `$("#rowed5").setGridParam({ postData: {test_value:'<?PHP echo $table?>'}});`

Comment: I think yes, but it depends where and when you want to do this. You can just add postData  object direct as grid options when you build the grid - i.e `jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({...,postData:test_value:'<?PHP echo $table?>',...});  `

Comment: thanks sir, i have tried it, but iam not getting the expected result. actually i am storing the table name in a variable $table_name and i want to use this variable in php whenever an inline edit is saved, i am updating the record like below, `if($_POST['oper']=='edit'){
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$table_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['test_value']);
$status=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
if (!empty($_POST['status']))
{
$sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET status=$status,update_time=now() WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($sql);
}}`

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: the version is 4.14.0 sir

Comment: i have updated my code sir, i tried this     `{serializeRowData : function( post_to_server ) {
    var postParams  =  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
    if(postParams.hasOwnProperty('test_value') ) {
    post_to_server['test_value'] = postParams.test_value;
    }
    return post_to_server;
    },` but the test_value posted is empty.

Comment: sir i tried with static table name like this `postData: {test_value:'mystaticvalue'}`,  not working

Comment: Sorry for this long discussion, @davidb look carefully at the code - the serializeRowData is a part of grid options - you have enter your code wrong - see my last update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151503/discussion-between-davidb-and-tony-tomov).

Answer (score 1):

The main reason of your problem seems to me the option `cellEdit : true` **together** with inline editing methods like `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`. jqGrid supports three main **alternative** editing modes: incline editing, cell editing and form editing. If you enable cell editing with respect of the option `cellEdit: true` then **the callback `onSelectRow` will be never called**. Cell editing means typically **cell selection** instead of *row selection*. Thus the usage of `cellEdit: true` prevent typically calling of `onSelectRow` callback. New option `noCellSelection: true` is introduced in free jqGrid 4.15.0, which will be soon released. It allows to combine row selection with cell editing, but calling of `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow` is not good even in case of `cellEdit: true` with `noCellSelection: true`, because it will cancel just started cell editing.

My short recommendation is following: you should decide, which *one* editing mode you want to use. In case of usage cell editing (`cellEdit: true`) you should remove unused `onSelectRow` and `serializeRowData` and to add `serializeCellData` or alternatively `beforeSubmitCell` to extend the data posted to the server. The code of `serializeCellData` could be the same, which you use for `serializeRowData`. Alternatively the callback `beforeSubmitCell` could return object `{test_value: postParams.test_value}` or `{}`. The object returned from `beforeSubmitCell` will be combined (extended) with the standard parameters of cell editing (see [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server)).

Comment: sir could you please help me with an example

Comment: @davidb: I'm not sure, which help you need. I suggested you two alternative ways: 1) usage of inline editing, 2) usage of cell editing. Which one you want to use? I described you that if you choose the way 1, then you need just remove `cellEdit : true`. If you choose the way 2, then you can just rename `serializeRowData` to `serializeCellData` and remove unused `onSelectRow` callback.

Comment: i have updated my code sir, `cellEdit : true` and renamed `serializeRowData` to `serializeCellData`, could you please help advice if anything needs to be done

Comment: @davidb: I don't see any error. What problem you have now? Do you started the code in debugger (Developer Tools of Chrome/IE)? Will be `serializeCellData` called now (you can set breakpoint here)? Will be the edited data send to `functions.php` (you can use Network tab of Developer Tools to see Network traffic). You can use additionally free tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the HTTP traffic between the client and the server.

Comment: ,sir im getting this below error, `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).jqGrid is not a function at HTMLTableElement.serializeCellData (cam.php:223) at HTMLTableElement.serializeFeedback (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:11) at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:14) at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.saveCell (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:14)at n.fn.init.$.fn.jqGrid (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:11)at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:14)at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`

Comment: @davidb: Please use **jquery.jqGrid.src.js** instead of **jquery.jqGrid.min.js** if you has an error. One will see line numbers, which will be useful. You should append the errors to the text of your question and post short comment inform me about changes of the text of your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151603/discussion-between-davidb-and-oleg).

Comment: @davidb: I have to do my main job. If you want to speed-up solving the problem you should create the demo, which one could debug. The page created by your PHP program contains test data. You can open the source of the page and use the code to create jsfiddle demo.